# active Mq delivery policy

Tags: activemq-classic

Can you tell me the meaning of this function, what they do? I have tried to find it on Google but i can not be understand.

I am setting the redelivery policy.

```
policy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);
    policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
    policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(2);
    policy.setRedeliveryDelay(5000)
```

Answer (score 4):

Messages are redelivered to a client when any of the following occurs:

- A transacted session is used and rollback() is called.
- A transacted session is closed before commit is called.
- A session is using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE and Session.recover() is called.

Once a message's redelivery attempts exceeds the maximumRedeliveries configured for the Redelivery Policy, a "Poison ack" is sent back to the broker letting him know that the message was considered a poison pill. The Broker then takes the message and sends it to a Dead Letter Queue so that it can be analyzed later on.

You can read more about message redelivery handling in Active MQ here:

http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

The the redelivery policy properties you are referring to are:

- maximumRedeliveries: Sets the maximum number of times a message will be redelivered before it is considered a poisoned pill and returned to the broker so it can go to a Dead Letter Queue (use value -1 to define infinite number of redeliveries)
- maximumRedeliveryDelay: Sets the maximum delivery delay that will be applied if the useExponentialBackOff option is set. (use value -1 to define that no maximum be applied) (v5.5)
- useExponentialBackOff: Should exponential back-off be used (i.e. to exponentially increase the timeout)
- backOffMultiplier: The back-off multiplier

All properties for the redelivery policy are described here:

http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html

Comment: Links without content in the post aren't considered answers. Could you please copy some of the relevant information into your answer, to prevent link dependency?

Comment: i want description, this link have no much matter

Comment: Good point, I am a bit new at this, I have updated the answer with more information

Answer (score 0):

Few points to add to those mentioned above

1. If you are using CLIENT_ACK as the acknowledgement mode and closing the session without acknowledging the latest message all the pending messages will be redelivered.
2. If you are using asynchronous message transfer and a `RuntimeException` is thrown inside `onMessage()` method the corresponding message will be redelivered.

All of the above is subjected to maximum redelivery tries of-course. After maximum redelivery tries the message will go to dead message queue(if you have configured) or will be simply dropped.

What you have asked is a type of redelivery policy. So in case a message has to be redelivered how much importance(delay) should be given to it's redelivery. If setUseExponentialBackOff is set for each redelivery of the same message delivery delay will increase exponentially.

All the properties available for redelivery policy are

[image]

For complete details look [here](http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html).